# What does #[account] do in Anchor beside adding constraints?

Tags: anchor, rust

I couldn't find anchor docs very clear about this. What is exactly the difference between these two structures:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Foo<'info> {
    pub bar: Signer<'info>,
}
```

and

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Foo<'info> {
    #[account]
    pub bar: Signer<'info>,
}
```

Does this really makes sense to have `#[account]` when we want no constraint on the given account?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer:**
The answer is that there's no difference. In this case, `#[account]` has no effect in the generated code. The reason for this is that the parsing logic for the `#[account]` macro in this specific case does nothing because no arguments are passed to it.

**Long-winded answer:**
You can see that [here](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/dbb36d211c754b4d1ffbaf654ef294ec41942156/lang/syn/src/parser/accounts/constraints.rs#L12). The call to `attr.parse_args_with` returns a list of comma-separated arguments for the `#[account]` macro. In this case, it returns nothing because there are no arguments, hence `constraints.add` is never called and the `parse` function generates zero constraints.

Since the resulting `ConstraintGroup` type is what anchor uses to generate the resulting code and it's "empty" in this case, nothing is generated. You can also see evidence of this in the codegen code [here](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/dbb36d211c754b4d1ffbaf654ef294ec41942156/lang/syn/src/codegen/accounts/constraints.rs#L8). Since we get back an empty vector, nothing gets generated.